# Результаты теста в очереди на переоткрытие используют текст из очереди закрытия

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

В очереди на переоткрытие попалось тестовое задание:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/54112

Нажал "Оставить закрытым" и получил сообщение:

> Это всего лишь проверка, чтобы оценить Вашу внимательность. Вы прошли проверку. Закрывать следует только вопросы с серьезными проблемами.

А должно быть ведь что-то типа

**Открывать надо только хорошие вопросы**

Comment: Другим не видно это сообщение, только вам. Скриншот сделаете?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я уже вкладку закрыл( Теперь по ссылке вижу то же, что и все. Но встречал уже не раз. Ещё встречу - заскриню.

Comment: сейчас поищу эту строку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сообщения проверок составляются из двух частей. Первые два предложения сообщают об успешном или неуспешном прохождении проверки.

Третье - о том, что делать в таких ситуациях. Оно одинаково для всех случаев закрытия, в любой из очередей.

Эта строка уже переведена следующим образом (Tx:3601):

> Closing is appropriate for questions like this.
>
> Закрывать следует только вопросы с серьезными проблемами.

Очевидно, что перевод не совсем точно передает смысл. Исправил на такой:

> Для вопросов с серьёзными проблемами подходящим действием является закрытие.

Строка исправится после ближайшего обновления боевой базы.

Можно предлагать и другие формулировки.

Comment: Не совсем то... В моём случае, в очереди на переоткрытие мне предложили плохой вопрос и для прохождения проверки надо было нажать "Закрыть". Так что нам нужна другая строка)

Comment: Аа, я понял. Тогда это верная строка, просто нужно скорректировать формулировку.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб исправил ответ и строку в базе.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо)